# multiple wsit-client.xml

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework, wsit

I have a web-app in which I have deployed multiple jax-ws based webservices clients. They all need wsit-client's of their own. I there any way for me to specify which wsit-client.xml file to use when instantiating the service class?

I would like to keep the wsit-client files separate for each webservices client by packaging it in the respective jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer from Sun seems promising:

https://blogs.oracle.com/ritzmann/entry/non_standard_wsit_configuration_file

It looks like the method:

public static Service create( URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName, InitParams properties)

still exists in the most current implementation of JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="mainclientconfig">

    <import location="WS1.xml"
        namespace="http://my.namespace.com/wsdl/WS1-1.0" />

    <import location="WS2.xml"
        namespace="http://my.namespace.com/wsdl/WS2-1.0" />

    <import location="WS3.xml"
        namespace="http://my.namespace.com/wsdl/WS3-1.0" />

</definitions>
```

where WS1.xml ist the original wsit-client.xml for the wirst WS-Client etc.